# Concatenate the single characters in texts

Tags: python, scikit-learn, string-concatenation

I have a list with company names, some of them has abbreviations. ex:

```
compNames = ['Costa Limited', 'D B M LTD']
```

I need to convert compNames of text to a matrix of token counts using the following. But this does not output columns for `B D M` in `D B M LTD`

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')
count_vect.fit_transform(compNames).toarray()
```

What is the best way to concatenate the single characters in a text?

```
ex: 'D B M LTD' to 'DBM LTD'
```

Comment: I don't understand what the criterion is for the decision about whether to concatenate or not. How do you decide that `D`, `B`, `M` should be concatenated to `DBM`, but `LTD` should remain separated. I mean, in this concrete example, it might be semantically obvious, but in order to come up with an algorithm, there needs to be a general criterion that'll work for all input in the desired way...

Comment: The algorithm should concatenate only the single characters (`B D M`) but not the words  (`LTD`).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean @anothernode. I have millions or company names in this list and I need to concatenate single characters together in every company name in the list. That is a general criterion I need.

Comment: I think any single characters (not next to non-blank) are meant.

Comment: Alright, now I get it.

Comment: You are right @ArndtJonasson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
string = 'D B M LTD'
print re.sub("([^ ]) ", r"\1", re.sub(" ([^ ]{2,})", r"  \1", string))
```

Awkward, but it should work. It introduces an additional space in front of LTD and then replaces "D " with "D", "B " with "B" and so on.

Comment: why you said its 'Awkward'? This seems to work fine. Any shortcomings?

Comment: One bug: `re.sub("([^ ]) ", r"\1", re.sub(" ([^ ]{2,})", r"  \1", "ffdjk g"))` -> `"ffdjkg"`

Comment: @Shana because it uses sub twice

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short function that breaks a string on white space characters to a list, iterates the list, builds a temporary string if the element is of length 1, appends the temp string to a new list when an element with length greater than one is encounters.

```
import re

a = 'D B M LTD'

def single_concat(s):
    out = []
    tmp = ''
    for x in re.split(r'\s+', s):
        if len(x) == 1:
            tmp += x
        else:
            if tmp:
                out.append(tmp)
            out.append(x)
            tmp = ''
    return ' '.join(out)

single_concat(a)
# returns:
'DBM LTD'
```

Comment: I don't think you really need `re` to just do a `split()`.. I just noticed this after writing essentially [the same algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694697/1619432) :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "D B M LTD"

first_part = ''
for chunk in re.compile("([A-Z]{1})\s").split(s):
    if len(chunk) == 1:
        first_part += chunk
    elif len(chunk) > 1:
        last_part = chunk

print(first_part + " " + last_part)
```

Prints `DBM LTD`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string = 'D B M LTD'
print re.sub(r"\+", r"", re.sub(r"\+(\w\B)", r" \1", re.sub(r"(\b\w) ", r"\1+", string)))
```

I'm using the + character as temporary, assuming there are no + characters in the string. If there are, use some other that doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Look, no `re`:

```
def mingle(s):
    """ SO: 49692941 """
    l = s.split()
    r = []
    t = []
    for e in l:
        if len(e) == 1:
            t.append(e)
        else:
            j = "".join(t)
            r.append( j )
            r.append( e )
            t = []

    return " ".join(r)

print( mingle('D B M LTD') )
```

prints

```
DBM LTD
```